# c# 4.0 - Shortening url using bit.ly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, bit.ly

I'll post in Twitter the shortcut links using bitly,
How can i do this ?

Comment: did you tried Twitter API and Bitly API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not perfectly clear what you're trying to do, but sounds like you're looking for the [bit.ly API](http://dev.bitly.com/code_libraries.html) - that link has C# libraries for you.

You will also need to make use of the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/).

Have a good read through those resources, understand how to authenticate (api key etc.), then use the c# libraries to make requests to those services.

You can then shorten urls, and post those shortened urls to twitter.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Twitter API and I'am using TweetWithMedia() to post in twitter message,image and link, all its work good, the link its very big and i want to make a shortcut for the link. i will use bit.ly API, Thanks